# Material-ui. Не применяются стили к <Box>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, create-react-app, material-ui

Всем привет. Начал изучать React. Также использую material-ui. Но столкнулся с такой проблемой: при кастомизации компонента Box не применяются указанные стили. Буду очень благодарен за любую наводку.

```
import s from "./Footer.module.css"
import {Box, Button, Container, Grid} from "@material-ui/core";

function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer>
            <Box bgcolor={"#1c1427"} color={"white"}>
                <Container maxWidth={"lg"}>
                    <Grid container spacing={5}>
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={8}>
                            <Box className={s.logo}>
                                <a>Logo</a>
                            </Box>
                            <Box borderBottom={1}>
                                <a>Работа выполнена в рамках учебного проекта</a>
                            </Box>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={1}>
                            <Box>
                                <Button variant={"outlined"} color={"white"}>Войти</Button>
                            </Box>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={1}>
                            <Box>
                                <Button variant={"outlined"} color={"white"}>Зарегистрироваться</Button>
                            </Box>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Container>
            </Box>
        </footer>
    )
}

export default Footer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стилизовать компоненты в **Material UI v.5** можно с помощью атрибута `sx`. Код должен выглядить вот так:

```
<Box sx={{ backgroundColor: '#1c1427', color: 'white' }}>
   ...
</Box>
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-box/#the-sx-prop